# Use one github project in others

Tags: github

I have some self-written toolbox, which I use in multiple projects. If i clone some project from github i always should clone this toolbox separately. Sorry for very naive question, is it possible to organize my work in a good way. I want during cloning project from github clone all my dependencies also.
Could you give me an advice how to reach this aim?

Comment: What language are you using and what package managers does it have available?

Comment: It is just MATLAB. Toolbox is partially MATLAB, partially .Mex (c++ lib for MATLAB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use git submodules to do this: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

While cloning a project with submodules use these commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/username/MainProject
cd MainProject
git submodule init
git submodule update
```